# Documentation required for US citizen to travel to Canada

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

My enhanced drivers license will not be here for another 2 weeks, I am from wa. state and want to go to Canada this week for a wedding shower.  I have the copy of the drivers License, my birth certificate..will I have any problems going and coming back in?